# (Version 4.0.0-beta.3) 'more' feature for remote date loading stopped working

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I just upgraded my select2 to the latest version in the subject and noticed that `more` loading stopped working.

```
select.select2({
    placeholder: select.data("placeholder"),
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: select.attr('multiple') ? true : false,
    ajax: {
        url: '/Common/GetEntityItems',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                searchTerm: term,
                page: page                            
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            var more = true;
            return { results: data.items, more: more };
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('error!');
        },
        formatResult: function (item) {
            return '<div>' + item.text + '</div>';
        },
        formatSelection: function (item) {
            return item.text;
        }                    
    }
});
```

Despite the unconditional `true` to `more` variable, `more` thing doesn't work any more. Do you see anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Brad,

in case you still looking for answer (it took me a couple of hours btw), you need to change

```
return { results: data.items, more: more };
```

to

```
return { results: data.items, pagination: { more: more } };
```

/Fred